# Unable to open saved excel file using urllib.request.urlretrieve (Sample link mentioned )

Tags: python, urllib

Currently, I'm using Flask with Python 3.
For sample purposes, here is a dropbox [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w1h6vw2st3wvtfb/Sample_List.xlsx?dl=0)

In order to fetch the file and save it, I'm doing the following.

`urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.dropbox.com/s/w1h6vw2st3wvtfb/Sample_List.xlsx?dl=0", "Sample_List.xlsx")`

The file is saved successfully to my project's root directory, however there is a problem. When I try to open the file, I get this error.

[image]

What am I doing wrong over here?

Also, is there a way to **get the file name and extension** from the URL itself? Example, filename = Sample_List and extension = xlsx...something like this.

Comment: you get the html instead of the `xlsx` to download it you should use direct link.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Any workaround that I can do to solve my problem?

Comment: try to read here https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/issues/89